# How to include the current timestamp in spacy's projects.yml scripts?

Tags: python, bash, time, yaml, spacy

I'm using [**spacy projects**](https://spacy.io/usage/projects) for a pipeline for training a dependancy parser pipeline for a custom Bulgarian language model. I want to retrain and reevaluate mutiple times with different datasets and tokenizer rulesets. For that, I need to put a `timestamp` on the evaluation metrics.

I do this by running `spacy evaluate ./models/model-best test.spacy -dp ./visualizations/ --output metrics-$(date +"%FT%H%M").json` to get a metrics file with the current time included in the name.

This scrtipt, however, does not work when it's part of the `project.yml` file. I tried different ways to escape the `"` and `%` characters, but nothing led to success. Any help will be much appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you could run this command from the project with `sh -c` if you can figure out the YAML escaping (I couldn't quickly), so if I wanted to do this, I'd just move the command into a shell script and call that from the project instead.